# Ошибка в Js слайдер помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, slider

Ребят скажите плиз где тут ошибка ? мне браузер говорит что ошибка в первой строке, но я делал всё по гайду 10 раз пере смотрел так и не понял в чём проблема  [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
JS

```
document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick = sliderLeft;


function sliderLeft() {
var polosa = document.getElementById('polosa');
  polosa.style.left = -128+'px';
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script src="js/1.js"></script>
  <title>Урок</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="polosa">
      <img src="img/giphy 11.gif" alt="">
      <img src="img/mani.gif" alt="">
      <img src="img/samurai 1.gif" alt="">
      <img src="img/Samurai champlu.gif" alt="">
      <img src="img/siluet_neboskreby_gorod_129089_1920x1080.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="img/avtomobil_most_noch_128169_1680x1050.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="img/politsiia_avtomobil_ulitsa_139136_1680x1050.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="slider-left">left</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#slider {
  width: 384px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#polosa {
  position: relative;
  background: blueviolet;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 896px;
}

#polosa img {
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;

}

#polosa::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick = () =>sliderLeft()`

Comment: @xydope Чем это принципиально отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: @igor ничем :D, вместо точки с запятой скобки в примере автора сам себе нарисовал. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А можно просто привязать к кнопке выполнении функции сдвига (В кнопке добавить `onclick="Ваша_функция();"`
 Пример:

```js
    function sliderLeft() {
        var polosa = document.getElementById('polosa');
        polosa.style.left = -128+'px';
    }
```

```css
    #slider {
        width: 384px;
        height: 128px;
        border: 5px solid black;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }

    #polosa {
        position: relative;
        background: blueviolet;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 896px;
    }

    #polosa img {
        float: left;
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;

    }

    #polosa::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="slider">
    <div id="polosa">
        <img src="img/giphy 11.gif" alt="">
        <img src="img/mani.gif" alt="">
        <img src="img/samurai 1.gif" alt="">
        <img src="img/Samurai champlu.gif" alt="">
        <img src="img/siluet_neboskreby_gorod_129089_1920x1080.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="img/avtomobil_most_noch_128169_1680x1050.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="img/politsiia_avtomobil_ulitsa_139136_1680x1050.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<button id="slider-left" onclick="sliderLeft()">left</button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: Денис можно с вами как то связаться ?

Comment: @BERSERKER https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103720/berserker-and-denis640kb

Answer (score 2):

Вы обращаетесь к элементу до того, как  он создается при загрузке страницы.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById('slider-left').onclick = sliderLeft;
});
```

Comment: Я не давно начал изучать JS обьясни плиз по подробней ?
у него в гайде всё работает https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casgv9Y8I1w&list=PLL5_RVHtQuicc0-BSxHr62EEdlzj5cQQL&index=12
и я не понимаю что значит window.addEventListener("load", function() 
что они означают ?

Comment: @BERSERKER Ваш js находится **и выполняется** в `head`. В это время никаких DOM-элементов еще нет. А Вы пытаетесь один из них найти и назначить ему какое-то свойство. С элементами надо работать, когда страница загрузилась.

Comment: То есть в скрип добавить defer?
или перетащить строчку под конец кода ?

Comment: @BERSERKER "я не понимаю что значит window.addEventListener" - Что Вам выдает Google на запрос "window addEventListener load"?

Comment: @BERSERKER Я написал в ответе, что надо сделать. Чем Вас это не устраивает?

Comment: Меня всё устраивает) просто хочу разобраться ( я же сказал что я новичок) я изучать всё это стал недавно

Comment: @BERSERKER Вы почeму-то решили не использовать для скрипта атрибут `defer`, как сделано в видео. Я показал, как сделать без него.

Comment: Всё понял!) большое спасибо теперь понял, и последний вопрос как хорошо вы знаете  Верстку HTML CSS JS ? Я просто учусь по гуглу и ютубу и хочу найти знающего человека в этом (само сабой не за бесплатно)

Comment: @BERSERKER Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа. Верстку и т.д. я знаю не очень хорошо.

Comment: Ну а Js ? мы с друзьями делаем сервер и мне нужно научится всему этому в  Html и Css как то ориентируюсь но в JS я затупок ) можно сами как то связаться и обговорить на эту тему ?

Comment: @Igor не скромничай ))) Лайк за быстрый ответ )

Comment: Можно с вами как то связаться насчёт обучения ? по JS